# GRPC with JavaScript Client?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, grpc-web, grpc-node

Hello I m trying to find ref for GRPC with JavaScript Client.
I checked tried to search but is generally refer Node Library.

In my implementation I have .NET GRPC server and have react UI app
so just want to check is GRPC client support  JavaScript as client
or do we have any ref for GRPC for react.js.

as client I want to use grpc with JavaScript or react.js

Comment: gRPC cannot be used directly from the browser so gRPC-Web fills this gap - [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/browser?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is probably a good place to start (as you are using .NET). Note that there is an ['official' generator](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) and a range of alternatives ([this article](https://buf.build/blog/protobuf-es-the-protocol-buffers-typescript-javascript-runtime-we-all-deserve) covers one and has links to others).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [grpc-web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) library in your JavaScript application. Here is a [simple example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld/client.js):

```js
// Protobuf generated with script
const {HelloRequest, RepeatHelloRequest,
       HelloReply} = require('./helloworld_pb.js');
const {GreeterClient} = require('./helloworld_grpc_web_pb.js');

var client = new GreeterClient('http://' + window.location.hostname + ':8080',
                               null, null);

// simple unary call
var request = new HelloRequest();
request.setName('World');

client.sayHello(request, {}, (err, response) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`Unexpected error for sayHello: code = ${err.code}` +
                `, message = "${err.message}"`);
  } else {
    console.log(response.getMessage());
  }
});
```